# Access: Missing entries in the TableDef.fields collection

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I'm using a VBA procedure to add some fields to an existing table by modifying its TableDef.
As the names of these fields could change between imports, I opted to delete the old entries before adding new ones.
The code below has no problem adding the fields from the library table (P6 Files AC).
Where it goes wrong is in deleting existing entries. The count at the beginning always gives the correct number of fields. But the FOR EACH statement jumps over some of the entries.
Running the code repeatedly, ultimately does delete all of the field that meet the criteria.

```
Set curdb = CurrentDb()
Set tdf = curdb.TableDefs("TASK")
Debug.Print tdf.Fields.Count
tdf.Fields.Refresh
    For Each fld In tdf.Fields
        Debug.Print fld.Name
        If InStr(1, fld.Name, "AC#", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then tdf.Fields.Delete fld.Name
        Next fld
        
'add the field from the P6 Files AC table
strSQL = "SELECT [P6 Files AC].Field_Name " & _
    "FROM [P6 Files AC] " & _
    "ORDER BY [P6 Files AC].Field_Name;"

Set newfields = curdb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
    With newfields
        Do Until .EOF()
            tdf.Fields.Append tdf.CreateField(!field_name, dbText, 15)
            .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be much simpler to *link* the source table, then use it as source in a create-table query:

```sql
SELECT * 
INTO [TASK]
FROM [P6 Files AC];
```

It will overwrite an existing TASK table.

Answer (score 2):

When you loop a collection of items, such as fields in a table, to delete them, you need to do so in reverse order, otherwise the current field positions get out of sync to those being considered in your loop. Try something like:

```vb
Sub sDeleteFields()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("tblRatings")
    lngCount = tdf.Fields.Count - 1
    For lngLoop1 = lngCount To 0 Step -1
        If InStr(tdf.Fields(lngLoop1).name, "AC#") > 0 Then
            tdf.Fields.Delete tdf.Fields(lngLoop1).Name
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
    tdf.Fields.Refresh
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sDeleteFields", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Note that fields are 0-indexed, so the first field is at position 0, and the last field is at position count-1.

Regards,